# Can a plosive be pronounced without an audible release sound following it?

Tags: pronunciation

When a plosive is at the beginning of a word, the pronunciation naturally flows into the vowel which follows it.  The extra vowel sound following the plosive seems to give the plosive a very obvious end.  When the plosive is at the end of a word, I find myself releasing the stop with an extra bit of sound at the end which does not seem to be part of the plosive itself.

Consider "cat" which is generally transcribed as [kæt].  I feel like I pronounce it more like [kætə].

Another example is [med].  I find that I cannot detect the difference between [med] and [men] unless I audibly release the [d] in [med].  (This also begs the question of how to pronounce a word which ends in a nasal followed by a plosive on the same articulation point like [lænd]).

I'm looking for two pieces to the answer:

1. Is the extra sound an actual feature of the pronunciation of the plosive?
2. If yes, is this feature unique to English or is it common to all languages with plosives at the end of a word.

Comment: It's possible to pronounce an unreleased plosive, but only at the end of an utterance. Otherwise you have to release it to get to the next phone. It happens in English with short words like _Yup_ and _Nope_, where the final /p/ is simply the gesture of shutting the mouth. Normally plosives are released in English, and under the appropriate circumstances, they are aspirated or affricated during the release. The actual sound produced during transition may be significant (as with aspiration) or not. In any event, there is no contrast.

Comment: As I pointed out in another context earlier today, unless I actually "release the plosive" in order to start another sound, it doesn't seem to make any difference to me whether my ***yup*** ends with a /p/ or a glottal stop.

Comment: @JohnLawler we have to release even utterance final plosives. An unreleased plosive is usually fatal!

Comment: Not if your nose works.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ah ,but that would just be a (ninaudible) nasal release.

Comment: "Unreleased plosives" means plosives that do not release into plosion. [n] is one such, if you like; but all I meant is that life goes on, even after an unreleased plosive occurs.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a more linguistic than ELL answer, but here goes:

(1) The stops *t*, *p*, *k*, when syllable-final, undergo glottal reinforcement in English.  This minor glottal occlusion does not wholly impede the airstream.  So, when the stop is released, the remainder of the air is released too.  This is reminiscent of an unvoiced schwa, which accounts for what you hear after the *t* in *cat*.  In terms of IPA transcription, one tends not to write the fine, automatic phonetic detail, and, so, for English, one marks only the preglottalization, as in [kʰæˀt].

(2) Crosslinguistically, the behaviour of syllable-final *t*, *p*, *k* varies.  In Kiowa, for instance, as described by JP Harrington, *t* and *p* undergo complete glottal closure and are unreleased.  In German, they are lightly post-aspirated. There are, however, only a certain number of perceptually distinct things you can do with your articulatory tract. So, my guess is, there'll be other languages that behave as English does.

Comment: Does a native Kiowa speaker hear a difference between the unreleased syllable-final plosive sound and a nasal (or other similar sound)?  I find I cannot detect a difference between [men] and [med] if I do not audibly release the [d] in [med]!

Comment: @just.another.programmer Is English your native language? I find I never release the /d/ and can still see a minimal pair.

Comment: @Ledda Yes, I was raised speaking US English (San Diego to be precise).  I know very little about defining / detecting the difference between sounds (I only took one linguistics course in college), but there's no feature I could define which distinguishes between the two.

Comment: @just.another.programmer Really?! A vowel preceding a nasal coda is generally partly nasalized, so that should give you one difference between _men_ and _med_.  Moreover, if you don't release the _d_, then you should get a substantial durational difference between the _n_, a continuant, and _d_, a stop.

Comment: <med> might sound like <men> when you have a cold? Have you tried that out? A nasal and a voiced stop are very articulatorily different and I myself can quite easily tell the difference between the two. Do you think you could be able to provide a recording of your saying of each one?

Comment: Colds make you speak less nasally, rather than more nasally (contrary to common belief, but obviously, if your nose is blocked, then you can't channel an airstream through it).  So, yes, _med_, _bed_, _men_, _ben_ would tend to converge when you're coldy, though other, more subtle secondary articulations might still distinguish them.  But that stuff lies beyond what I know about.